# python find out which lists have been added to diagnose memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I'm trying to diagnose a memory leak. By using tools like `pympler` and `objgraph`, I can see that a lot of large lists are added after each iteration of the main loop in my program code. This is unexpected behavior - the number of lists should stay constant after the program starts, not grow in the loop.

I would like to look at the lists that are added after each iteration. I've tried to do this via something similar to the following (very simplified) code:

```
def my_func():
    import objgraph
    import gc
    existing = objgraph.by_type("list")
    for item in to_do():
        gc.collect()
        new = objgraph.by_type('list')
        diff = [item for item in new if item not in existing]
        existing = new
        do_something(item)
```

However, I get the following error when I attempt this:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I understand why this is happening, but I still need a way to investigate the new lists. How can I get access to just these new lists so that I can investigate the memory leak?

Comment: Adding print statements is a simple way, albeit probably not the best way.  this is where having a good debugger is handy.

Comment: I am using pdb in conjunction with PyCharm; don't know of any better combination of debuggers (happy to get recommendations). I don't think print statements will help. I have two very large lists (~60k items) and I need to figure out what has been added to the new list without triggering the `RuntimeError`.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, using `item not in existing` blows up because it checks for equality, like `a == b`, which requires traversal of nested structures. However, equality is actually not what we are interested in the first place. Instead, we want to compare *identity*, i.e. `a is b`. This is a lot cheaper, as it is independent of the object content.

As a list comprehension, we could say

```
diff = [n for e in existing for n in new if n is e]
```

That is rather wasteful, as we keep searching all of `existing` even if we've found a match.

```
def is_in(item, collection):
    for c in collection:
        if item is c:
            return True
    return False

diff = [item for item in new if not is_in(item, existing)]
```

The fastest solution should be acquiring the identities in `existing` once and putting them into a set for more efficient searching:

```
existing_ids = {id(item) for item in existing}
diff = [item for item in new if id(item) in existing_ids]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an API debugger, e.g. the one coming with [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).
Set a breakpoint at a sensible point within your iteration and go through the execution step by step.

Comment: I do use PyCharm in conjunction with other methods; this doesn't seem to answer my question. I need to figure out what the new lists are that are being added into memory. How will PyCharm help me figure that out, given that there are around 60,000 old lists and 65,000 new lists? Is there a functionality in PyCharm that would help me find just the new lists?

Comment: Using breakpoints, you can see which objects are added or modified after every line's execution. It also allows you to either traverse into a function call (if it's not compiled code) to go through the function step by step, or else move right to the end of the function. This should allow you to figure out where and how the change happens

Comment: I do know how to use the PyCharm debugger. It doesn't help. My lists are too large for it to handle, so I can only ever see the first couple of hundred items at a time. Furthermore, there is no guaranteed order to the lists, so a visual inspection of the huge new/old lists would only get me so far.

Comment: I take it traversing into the function call is not an option? Can you limit the size of your input list? Or does it break down if you don't provide the entire 60k items? Also, to at least have a look at the newly added items, convert your input and output lists into sets and have a look at the difference.

Comment: No. The above code is, as I mentioned, a gross oversimplification of the actual code, so traversing into the function doesn't help. There is no single input list; I am retrieving a list of all lists that are in memory by using the `objgraph` library. I can't convert the resulting list of lists into a set because it contains lists, which are unhashable.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. If the inner lists are sortable, you could try doing an in-place sort of `existing` and `new` and iterating over them in parallel until you find an entry that's only in new (and isn't the `existing`  list that you created in your first objgraph call)

Comment: They are not sortable because their contents are arbitrary, consisting of a mix of locals/globals, database queries, error messages, etc.

Comment: Doubled back in my thinking and had a look at the original recursion error issue again. See my new answer